# Seeing TestNG progress in TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, testng

We are running selenium tests using TestNG in TeamCity.

Is there a way to know the progress of the current run beyond the progress bar and build log?

Information of interest is:

- Which tests were run and passed
- Which tests were run and failed
- ...

Thx

Answer (score 1):

As I know testng plugin for teamcity does not have such option. You can try real-time reporter e.g. [extentreports](http://extentreports.relevantcodes.com/). It could be easily connected via testng listener and pass results to report server.

Here is a link to another question which I answered recently which addresses something similar to what you're looking for with ExtentReports.

[ITestListener - ExtentReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37723538/itestlistener-extentreport/37812118#37812118)

Comment: As addittion, I haven't saw such functionality in TC, Bamboo or Jenkins. We have Jenkins in our company and develop additional testing dashboard to show test excution in real time.

Answer (score 0):

TeamCity can report the tests in a build and you should really get that in order to use TeamCity at full power. It can list the test failures in a build with details, display test history, you can assign investigations of a test to your team members or mute the test failures...

If you use TeamCity's Ant or Maven build steps, TestNG tasks should be recognized [automatically](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Java+Testing+Frameworks+Support) and build status should turn into something like "Tests failed:​ 1 (1 new),​ passed:​ 301".

Otherwise try to generate XML report in one of supported format and use [XML Report](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/XML+Report+Processing) build feature in TeamCity.

Yet another alternative is to report the tests in a completely custom way through TeamCity [service messages](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests).

All these approaches should update TeamCity build status and details as soon as the test is reported by the build tool. For service messages this is as soon as a test finish is reported, for Ant this is after each test run, for Maven this is after finishing tests of a module and for the XML test report build feature, this is while the XML is being saved on disk, even in incomplete form.

If you are rather looking for a specific test progress, that can be seen in the build log or you can [notify](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildProgress) TeamCity about stages in the build from within the test/script.

Comment: But i was looking about progress in real time, for history i know that TC supports it out of the box.

Comment: Updated to note that tests are reported in TeamCity as soon as the build tool reports them.